# extractting image link in python parsing xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, extract, urllib

I execute this python script to fetch the image with respective xpath from a prticular website..but this is printing only "[]"

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
import re


html_string = urllib.urlopen("http://www.gemselect.com/actinolite-cats-eye/actinolite-cats-eye-379734.php")
dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(html_string.read())
product_table = dom.xpath("/html/body/div/table[2]/tr/td/div[2]/table[1]/tr[3]/td[1]/img/@src")

for link in product_table:      
    print link
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regex to search for all jpg URL's starting with `/photos/`:

```
import re
re.findall('/photos.*jpg',html_string.text)

['/photos/actinolite-cats-eye/actinolite-cats-eye-gem-379734a.jpg',
 '/photos/actinolite-cats-eye/actinolite-cats-eye-gem-379734a.jpg',
 '/photos/actinolite-cats-eye/actinolite-cats-eye-gem-379734b.jpg',
 '/photos/actinolite-cats-eye/actinolite-cats-eye-gem-379734c.jpg']
```

Comment: yeah i also got this but this is not any part of image url

Comment: http://www.gemselect.com/photos/actinolite-cats-eye/actinolite-cats-eye-gem-379734a.jpg 
this  is the total image url